# Где должен быть медиа плеер?

Tags: java, android, mediaplayer

Где должен быть реализован медиа плеер в приложении? В сервисе, в отдельном классе или достаточно в MainActivity?

Comment: Зависит от того, в какой момент и как долго этот медиа плеер должен играть. MediaPlayer, реализованный в `Activity` будет остановлен и уничтожен при закрытии этой `Activity`. Реализация в сервисе такой проблеммы не имеет. Выделять код в отдельный класс или нет - ваше решение, которое на работу кода никак не повлияет. Прошу уточнить Ваш вопрос.

Comment: @DanielShatz В моем конкретном случае реализация такова, есть приложение в котором порядка 100 фрагментов прокручиваемых `ViewPager` и в каждом фрагменте есть разное количество пунктов `RecyclerView` и в каждом пункте есть ссылка на `mp3` файл из папки `raw`. Я реализовывал всю логику плеера в адаптере `Recycler` но это вообще не то.

Comment: ссылка на mp3 - имеете ввиду кнопка чтобы начать играть?

Comment: Рекомендую выделить медиа плеер в сервис. Активности могут быть уничтожены, например при повороте экрана и в таком случае медиа плеер, реализованный в активности тоже будет уничтожен.